# Update a FORMTEXT to a MERGEFIELD VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I have a project that I will likely be doing pretty regularly so I think a macro or vba module would be worth looking into.

The document has several [FORMTEXT] [FORMCHECKBOX] and such and I would like to automate replacing the [FORMTEXT] with {MERGEFIELD *formtextname*}.  I've sone similar with {command} from Crystal to {mergefield } but that was just word replacement not field type.  I found things about wdFormtextfield and wdMergeField just not sure how to .find type wdformtext.  I assume if I can .find the type I can then .Replace with wdMergeField.  I will be looping through the document.  Any thoughts?

I might be going the wrong way but this is what I am thinking

```
 Sub Change_FormTextToMergeField()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim StrFld As String 'change to a wd type for formtext
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "\{*\}"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            i = 1
            'add .Replace code to replace wdFieldFormTextInput with wdFieldMergeField
            MsgBox .Words.Parent            
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Sample Doc](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AhN1TI6_h-Iy2HUQ0naccWvcN79f?e=j0wjxX)

Comment: A link to a sample document would be useful here. For how to do this, see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: Sample Doc linked above

Comment: The Replace function does not work for fields. Find can find them, but Replace can't create them. With field codes displayed, I think you could replace "Formtext" with " Mergefield but I have not tried this. You would want to turn off screen updating, toggle field code display, and run it on your fields, then toggle field codes back to results and turn on screen updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The following procedure converts all FormFields to MergeFields perserving bookmarks as the Mergefield name

```
Sub FormFieldToMergeField()    '
    ' A scratch Word macro coded by Charles Kenyon - based on Greg Maxey format
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393869/update-a-formtext-to-a-mergefield-vba
    ' 2023-02-10
    ' started with Doug Robbins macro https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/convert-formtext-fields-into-bookmarked-content/1f2d7aa2-a335-4667-9955-998d0525ba09
    ' Converts FormFields to Mail Merge Fields - the Bookmark name becomes the mergefield name
    ' If no FormField bookmark, then mergefield says Unnamed
    '
    '   DECLARE VARIABLES / CONSTANTS
    Dim oRng   As range
    Dim oFld   As Field
    Dim strName As String
    Dim i      As Long
    '================================================
    '   ACTIONS
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo lbl_Exit
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set oRng = .FormFields(i).range
            strName = .FormFields(i).Name
            If strName = "" Then strName = "Unnamed Field " & i
            .FormFields(i).Delete
            oRng.Select
            Set oFld = .Fields.Add(range:=oRng, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=strName)
            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        Next i
    End With
    '   EXIT PROCEDURE
lbl_Exit:
    '   CLEAR ERROR HANDLER AND OBJECTS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenRefresh
    On Error GoTo -1
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oFld = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

If there is no bookmark, the mergefield will be to Unnamed.

[Instructions for Installing Macros from Forums or Websites](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) by Word MVP Graham Mayor

Comment: I like that.  Very simple and elegant.   Any good suggestions on learning VBA for Applications?

Comment: I've added a link at the end that will at least help with this macro. **Learning vba:** *How far down the rabbit hole do you want to go?* Start here: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA.htm. I've taken good online courses on it from Udemy's Grant Gamble. How much programming background do you have? In many ways it is constrained logic with arcane rules.

Comment: Good book: Writing Word Macros http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=1565927257/balancecheckbookA/

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with programming, just not VBA and not the constrained application-specific version.  Most of my programming is in C, Python, Php, ... so I am familiar with Object Oriented languages.  Thank you for the direction and code.  Looks like I have some light reading coming up :) I'll take a look at Gamble since Udemy is having their bi weekly sale